# ASP.Net Core saving base64 string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Image model:

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public long ImagelId { get; set; }
    public string base64 { get; set; }
}
```

Which I use like following:

```
public class CoreGoal
{
    [Key]
    public long CoreGoalId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }


    public CoreGoal()
    {

    }
}
```

I am using MySql database. I intend to store possibly multiple images as base64 strings against each CoreGoal.

Whenever I make a POST request with base64 strings, it is successful, however a large portion of the the string is chopped while saving to the database.

Am I using a wrong data structure for storing base64 i.e. string? Is it a problem in my ASP.Net code or is it a MySql limitation?

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

My Repository class:

```
public class CoreGoalRepository : ICoreGoalRepository
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _db;

    public CoreGoalRepository(WebAPIDataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    //Add new
    public void CreateCoreGoal(CoreGoal coreGoal)
    {
        _db.CoreGoals.Add(coreGoal);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Get all
    public IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAllCoreGoals()
    {
        return _db.CoreGoals
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.Benefits)
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.Images)
            .ToList();
    }
}

public interface ICoreGoalRepository
{
    void CreateCoreGoal(CoreGoal coreGoal);
    IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAllCoreGoals();
}
```

My controller:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CoreGoalController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICoreGoalRepository _coreGoalRepository;

        //Controller
        public CoreGoalController(ICoreGoalRepository coreGoalRepository) {
            _coreGoalRepository = coreGoalRepository;
        }

        //Get methods
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAll()
        {
            return _coreGoalRepository.GetAllCoreGoals();
        }

        //Create
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CoreGoal item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _coreGoalRepository.CreateCoreGoal(item);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCoreGoal", new { id = item.CoreGoalId }, item);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Could be getting truncated by the database. Check the length of the string versus the length of the field in the db.

Comment: How big is the image, you're trying to save? And how much does it actually save?

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't save anything to your database.  It's some other technology, looks like you're using EF 6 or EF Core. From a migrator like FluentMigrator? Is it an existing database?  Need to answer these before this can be definitively diagnosed.

Comment: Since you are not sure about using your datamodel, I would suggest to choose between: 1. if you want to stick on strings, store a path reference to the image which is relocated in a folder accessible by your AspNet app. 2. Use BLOB fields in your record and let mySql handle it. Then you can implement the base64 serialization/deserialization in the back-end or front-end. If you google about your question there are a lot of pages (and duplicates of this question as well) and maybe you'll find some more patterns.

Comment: @MarcL.Yes I am using EF core and I use package manager for migrations.

Comment: I would save them as `byte[]` with `varbinary(max)`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I saved it as byte[] and now it is being saved in database as blob. However, the returned string is still partial. I am updating my question with few other details.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the post request return also the object created as a JSON, so you can see the URL, or put a break point in your post and see the value of base64 string.

If the URL is ok then its the Db, so you need to manually set the max size of the URL with the attribute [StringLength(length)]